# Redirecting broken links (from external site)

Tags: seo, redirects

In webmaster tools we found that a bunch of sites are linking to non existent pages on our site. So far I can see 50,000+ links. Is there any downside to redirecting all of these broken links to a working page?

Answer (score 1):

you can (and it's recommended to) use [301 redirect](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9322454/syntax-for-301-redirect-of-www-to-non-www-using-httpd-conf) in order to redirect users from a broken link to a real-page.

Comment: I know it's possible to do so, but I don't know whether Google would consider it "dodgy" as we suddenly have tons of inbound links from dodgy sites.

Comment: 301 redirect is totally fine from SEO perspective.

Comment: "suddenly have tons of inbound links" - No, you already have tons of inbound links that aren't working - fixing them will not appear "dodgy" in the least.

Comment: danlefree is right!